# generate date of week interval in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want a series in PostgreSQL which gives the date of every week interval before that date

**Examples**

> ```
> 1)  Date Selected is 05/31/2013
>     So the series must be :
>     05/31/2013 
>     05/24/2013
>     05/17/2013
>     05/03/2013
>     04/26/2013
>
> 2)  Date Selected is 05/20/2013
>     So the series must be :
>     05/20/2013 
>     05/13/2013
>     05/06/2013
>     04/29/2013
>     04/22/2013
> ```

**What I have done:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM generate_series('2013-05-03 00:00'::timestamp,'2013-05-31 12:00', '1 weeks')
```

- It gives an increasing series from 2013-05-03.
- I want a decreasing series from 2013-05-31

Answer (score 7):

Is it what you're after?

```
SELECT *
  FROM generate_series('2013-05-31 12:00'::timestamp,
                       '2013-05-03', '-1 weeks');
```

Comment: For anyone finding this later and getting errors - the `date,date,interval` form of `generate_series` is relatively new. In older versions you can use a regular integer series and multiply by `INTERVAL '-1' WEEK`